# Can't log in my ubuntu laptop, login loop

Tags: command-line, permissions, login

Can anyone help me, I cant log-in to my laptop. Looks like its just looping back to the login screen.

what may have caused it, I was working on an AWS EC2 lab and after setting up an instance i downloaded the PEM/PPK saved it in a folder. Then I had to open the terminal and and type `chmod 600 ~/ <pathToPem>` see Image below, I got an error so I put `sudo chmod 600 ~/ pathname`. (nearly sure this is why I'm getting my problem) when I ran the second command It couldn't find the path and when I checked my files/folder in home a lot had disappeared? so at that stag I logged out and tried to log back in and just seem to be stuck in a loop.

Can anyone help me get back in and undo what I have done. I can get the text log in and get in that way but don't seem to have permissions to do anything.

tried to run `ls -la .Xauthority` and get ls: cannot access .Xauthority: No such file or directory.

[image]

Comment: No I downloaded the file to a folder called Amazon. and ran the command 'chmod 600 ~/ /Amazon/qwiklab-133-5018.pem'. When I press 'Ctrl + Alt + F4' I can log in but don't have any permissions. and If i run 'sudo su' and put my password in I can go into my documents folder and they are all there. Did I do something with my permissions? and if so How do I change them back.

Comment: Yes that what I was thinking, but because i'm new to ubuntu I didn't want to take another chance. Got it working again. `chmod 755 ~/` and then `ls -l /home/yourusername`. Thanks very much for your help @Serg  really appreciate it. Can you put it as the answer so I can mark as answered and it might help someone else.

Comment: Yup, I'll post it in a minute. Let's just clean up the comment section. Add the original code you ran to your question, and whatever other relevant info you posted in the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

You have altered permissions to your home folder. To change the permissions back, login into the text console ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or any other F key from 1 to 6 ), then loginn as root with `sudo su` and do `chmod 755 ~/`

**Explanation**

In the original command that you ran there is space between `~/` and `/Amazon/qwiklab-133-5018.pem`. Shell treats them at two separate arguments to `chmod` command. You have effectively changed permissions on your home folder to 600, which is read/write permissions to only yourself. You can confirm the permissions to your home folder by loging in with `sudo su` and doing `ls -l /home/yourusername`. Replace yourusername with your actual user name. you should see line like this `-rw-------` there.

The reason why you couldn't log in graphically, is because the graphical log-in screen, the greeter, would need to read configs in your home folder, to set up the graphical environment. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> , which is just text interface environment, doesn't need such configs. That's why you are able to login there.

Comment: Good one! (and an upvote!)