# Stuck at login screen

Tags: kubuntu, login, lightdm

I have Dell Inspiron 1525 with Kubuntu 14.04. One fine day I can't login and stuck at login screen. So I started searching here and there nothing helped. But one article has given me idea of creating another user with admin privileges.so for me <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> worked and I was able to create a new user and and was able to give it root privileges. It started working fine when I'm putting second userid and password I'm able to log in with GUI but not with first userid and password. When I put my first user and password dialogue box asking for credentials disappears and background remains for 3-5 seconds leading to black and blank screen around 7-9 seconds. Dialogue box reappears without any error.
   So on virtual terminal[tty1] tried starting lightdm with a failure. As well i tried runnig X by "startx"command with out any error or output. When I give command of kwin it give me fatel error line in terminal. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Install different desktop manager**

More of a workaround than solution. Get to tty console, make sure you are connected (or connect with `nmcli` ). Install alternate desktop manager aka greeter. Examples:

`sudo apt-get install gdm`

`sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`

`sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter`

Note: if you are getting gdm, you will be prompted to choose default greeter upon installation, chose gdm; if you're getting lightdm type of greeter, you may want to specify that in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file; for example:

> [SeatDefaults]
>
> greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter

**2) Check permissions of your home folder:**

In the example of [this user](https://askubuntu.com/a/585640/295286), his home folder permissions were modified to be viewed only by him alone, and prevented the desktop manager from accessing relevant data. Get to the terminal and do `ls -dl /home/yourusername`. If you have permission set as `-rw-------`, you may want to do `sudo chmod 755 /home/yourusername`

**3) Abandon the old username and reclaim the home folder**

Change ownership first: `chown -hR yournewusername:yournewgroup /home/youroldusername`

Then copy the files into your new folder: `rsync -r /home/oldusername /home/newusername/oldfiles`
Note that if you have lots of data there, it might take a while, so don't freak out if rsync seems to hang; just let it finish doing its job first.

Comment: Extremely sorry for delay in responding. As I've created new user with admin privilege. Now I'll just copy stuck user's home folder and delete it. Then I'll create a new user with same he and replace its home folder. 
@Serg did you mention the same thing in option 3.

Comment: @m2k1981 basically, yes, option 3 is same idea. But in addition you change ownership of all files from old username to new. Just in case you have some files set to be owned only by your old username

Comment: Thanx for support I'll be trying 3 rd option as you have mention. And so I've accepted answer. But actually we till don't know what happened with my system.

Comment: Ok.  Let me know if everything works. I think most likely it's #1 , problem with the greeter.  Bht could be some other things too