# Can't login to ubuntu 17.10 login loop

Tags: command-line, permissions, login-screen

Can anyone help me, I cant log-in to my laptop. Looks like its just looping back to the login screen.

What may have caused it, I was downloading a dataset from [Kaggle](http://kaggle.com). Then I had to open the terminal and and type `chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json` [(as shown here)](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api), I got an error so I put `sudo chmod 600 ~/ pathname` When I ran the second command It couldn't find the path and when I checked my files/folder in home it said "You dont have the permission to access these files". I have tried the following methods from AskUbuntu forum:

1. [Can't log in my ubuntu laptop, login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585627/cant-log-in-my-ubuntu-laptop-login-loop)
2. [Ubuntu stuck on login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551991/ubuntu-stuck-on-login-screen/552016)

But the problem still exists.
After using the first method I see the following output on my terminal

[image: (Image 1)]

but I am still stuck at the login loop.

**EDIT :** The image I get after running the this command `find ~vat26 ! \( -readable -writable -user vat26 \( ! -type d -o -executable \) \) -ls |& tee /tmp/vat26-permissions.log` (as asked by @David Foerster) is this :
[image: (Image 2)]

Comment: Can you login via a term?  (ctrl+alt+f4).  Check your disk space also (`df -h`) as if you've got no space for necessary temporary files in your $HOME directory, login will stop & return you to login screen.  If you have space, permissions would be next...

Comment: Over the course of the diagnosis of this issue you may find [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814) or command-line oriented solutions from [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](/q/440087/175814) useful.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo -u vat26 find ~vat26 ! \( -readable -writable -user vat26 \( ! -type d -o -executable \) \) -ls |& tee /tmp/vat26-permissions.log` (skip the `sudo -u vat26` prefix if you're already logged in as user `vat26`). This will also save the output to a file `/tmp/vat26-permissions.log` which you can then share as described in the answers to the questions linked in my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: …although `sudo chmod 755 ~vat26` should fix the permission issue introduced by `chmod 600 ~/` (as by your question), which is essentially the same as [kukulo's answer](/a/1014783/175814) and [the accepted answer to one of the linked question](/a/585640/175814).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot a live session on your laptop from installation DVD or USB. Within live session in the file manager identify your drive. Open terminal and change directory to your home folder on the drive.

With

```
sudo chmod 755 /path_to_your_home_folder
```

you can fix your file permissions.

Note: path to your home folder will be in the live session like this: `/media/disk_UUID/home/username`

Comment: I am just wondering how it can be done without live session. Could you please explain?

Comment: If he is still logged in then sudo chmod 755 /home/user_name/ is appropriate.