# Login Loop and strange PWD

Tags: login, lightdm, gdm

I'm getting the infinite log in loop on Ubuntu for just one of my user accounts - I've tried all of the recommended solutions (modifying .Xauthority, /temp/ and using lightdm)

Strangely when I ctrl+shift+f3 and login to the problem account - my working directory is "/" rather than "/home/username/"

Incase it is relevant, my the permissions for the problem account are
`dr-------- 31 usrnm usrnm ...`

Does anybody know how I can fix or troubleshoot?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That should be at least `rwx` for your user.

Comment: You got it in one thanks very much! I ran ```sudo chmod a+rwx /home/usrnm/``` and can now log in!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't log in my ubuntu laptop, login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585627/cant-log-in-my-ubuntu-laptop-login-loop)

Comment: Hi, I had tried this solution and failed because "~" was directing to "~" - now that I understand the problem it was on the right lines

Comment: @Charlie griffin, please, don't put SOLVED in the title, but write an answer with the solution you found.

Answer (score 2):

(Solution with thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru))

The problem was with the permissions for `/home/usrnm/`. I fixed it by logging into the problem account by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then running `sudo chmod a+rwx /home/usrnm/`

Comment: More usual permissions would be `u=rwx,go=rx` or octal `755` (you don't really want **all* to be able to write to your home dir)